# Moving back to previous activity and refreshing it

Tags: android, android-activity

I am moving from activity A to B.I want that on click of a button in activity B i should go back to activity A and it should be refreshed(i am doing an api call in activity A).However if user is moving back from B to A by just backpressed on device it should NOT be refreshed.Is there any better way of doing this without recreating activity A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start activity B with Intent.startActivityForResult() and answer this request on your Button clickListener.

OnBackPress default behaviour won't do anything to your previous activity.

Please, be aware of life cycles.

Another ways of handling this is:
- Using singletons provided by your Application class.
- SharedPreferences updates handling on onResume (of Activity A).

Force yourself on using Fragments for small projects.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily by using **LocalBroadcastManager**. Have a look on this thread

[how to use LocalBroadcastManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager)

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html

Answer (score 0):

No and yes. Activity A has no *normal* way of knowing how Activity B was ended. But you can send something from B back to A an other way. See answer from @Masum

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you want the `Activity` A to be refreshed, just launch it again via an `startActivity(new Intent(this, A.class))`.

If you don't want A to be refreshed, then call `finish()` method in `Activity` B.

For example, call `finish()` in `onBackPressed` in Activity B.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution i think is to use `onRestart()`

```
 @Override
public void onRestart() { 
    super.onRestart();
    //the activity is restared when click back and you could add what do you want for refresh here. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okey i just remembered `EventBus` . I think you can use event based solution .

In your activity A ,in `onCreate` and `onStart` add this line :

```
if (!EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(this)) {
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }
```

And add this `@Subscribe` method to your activity A :

```
 @Subscribe
 public void onMessageEvent(MyEvent event){
  //handle event
  //if any data coming handle data
  //trigger recreating methods etc ...
 }
```

Create new class like that :

```
public class MyEvent {
//you can add any values to send datas another activity

public MyEvent (){
  }

}
```

And in your activity B in Button's `onClick` method :

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new MyEvent());
```

Add this to your dependencies :

```
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
```

More information : [Eventbus](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/), and also you can look for [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/)